# Zoom H1 or Tascam DR-05 for violin recordings

Tags: recording, zoom, tascam

I've been recording my violin practice sessions with my smartphone for quite a while now. I'm not really satisfied with the recording quality so I've started looking for a portable recorder for ~100€. What I found were the Zoom H1 and Tascam DR-05.

I read some things about them, watched reviews and sample recording and even a video which compares both but I still can't decide.

Could you help me please? Which recorder is better suited especially for violin recordings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At that price, it really doesn't matter. For 100€ you will get what you get. For a real discussion on quality of sound, you will need to be looking at a more professional recording setup including condensor microphones and professional recorder. For simply recording practise sessions, just get something like a Zoom recorder. You will be able to hear what is going on with your performance and intonation - enough for it to be useful.